# Is ?: expression not always evaluated?

Tags: c++, c, expression, ternary-operator, evaluation

In Lisp, any expression can be evaluated. C++ adopts the concepts: "Expression", "Value", "Evaluation".

**Please refer to the C++ standard 5.1 if you don't know the relations between "Expression", "Value", and "Evaluation".**

I know ?: is an expression as same as + expression.

Any expression must be able to be evaluated and give a value. However `?:` expression seems not always so.

```
void f1() {}
void f2() {}

void test(bool b)
{
    b ? f1() : f2(); // OK. What's the value of this expression?
}
```

Any expression should have a value; `b ? f1() : f2();` is an expression; What's its value?

Any explanation?

**Updates and my own answer:**

Excerpted from the C++ standard 5.1:

> An expression can result in a value and can cause side effects.

Comment: `operator+` and ternary operator are completely different things.

Comment: They can both make an expression.

Comment: What is the question? In `int a = 1 ? f1() : f2();` a will always get the result of `f1()` and `f2()` will never be called. Both `f1` and `f2` are declared `void`, so my example would be invalid with your functions.

Comment: The result is always `f1()`

Comment: The result is `void`.

Comment: Whatever happens ultimate result will be `void`.

Comment: `f1 ()` will be evaluated after `true` is evaluated to, well, `true`... but the "value" of this expression is `void` since `f1` is declared to return `void`. In fact, since neither `f1` nor `f2` actually does anything, one might even make the case that whether you had `true` or `false` in this expression would make no difference.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman His question doesn't concern the semantics so much as the formal definition.  He's misunderstood something fundamental, because he seems to assume that _all_ expressions have a value, which isn't true.  (In Lisp, everything is a list, and  there is a special value, `nil`, the empty list, which is used in cases where there is no value.  In C++, we declare `void`, and there really isn't any value.)

Answer (score 5):

The value of the expression `b ? f1() : f2()` is either `f1()` or `f2()` depending on the value of `b`. In your case, both functions return `void`, so the value of the expression is *nothing*.

Comment: I think this answer doesn't catch the essence of this question. Compiler's optimazation is not its focus. It focuses on the concepts of "expression", "value", and "evaluation", which are important almost for any language.

Comment: @xmllmx: It doesn't make ANY difference. The expression value is still *nothing* irrespective of optimization level. In C++, value of an expression could be *nothing*. What essence are you looking for?

Comment: The first sentence is false.  Regardless of the value of the condition, the compiler synthesizes the type of the conditional expression from both of the controlled expressions, even if one of them will never be evaluated.  For example `true ? throw 42 : 42;` has type `int`, despite the fact that `throw 42` has type `void`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: The type is `void`. Also the first sentence doesn't disagree with what you said.So I don't understand why it is false;  Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Nawaz The type in his particular example is `void`, but it's not true that in general, the type of `a ? b : c` is the same as `b`.  It could be the same as `c`, or in some cases, a different type from either.

Comment: @JamesKanze: My answer is specific to the question, considering the types of both operands to be `void`.

Comment: @Nawaz But it's still misleading at best, and formally wrong.  The compiler will consider the type of `f2()`, as well as that of `f1()`, when considering the type of the total expression.  (And the question was about `b ? f1() : f2()`, not `true ? f1() : f2()`.)

Answer (score 2):

An expression *can* have a value.  Not all expressions have
a value, just as not all expressions have side effects.  An
expression does have a type; an expression of type `void`
doesn't have a value (since the set of values for `void` is
empty).

In an expression of the form `cond ? expr1 : expr2`, the type
is determined based on the types of `expr1` and `expr2`.  If
both `expr1` and `expr2` are `void`, then the type of the
conditional expression is `void`, and it has no value.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `true ? f1() : f2()` is `void`. From your edited part, your main question is whether a void type can be seen as an expression, the answer is YES.

> ### C++11 §3.9.1 *Fundamental types* Section 9
>
> The `void` type has an empty set of values. The `void` type is an incomplete type that cannot be completed. It is used as the return type for functions that do not return a value. Any expression can be explicitly converted to type `cv void` (5.4). An expression of type void shall be used only as an expression statement (6.2), as an operand of a comma expression
>   (5.18), **as a second or third operand of `?:`** (5.16), as the operand of `typeid`, or as the expression in a return statement (6.6.3) for a function with the return type `void`.

It doesn't make much sense to compare Lisp's concepts with C++. You can, at best, compare the concepts of C++ with other C family languages, such as C, Objective C, Java, etc. Lisp is like the on the other end of "language pool" from the C family languages.

Comment: Someone gave it downvote, without specifying the reason. VERY BAD.

Comment: void is a type, it can never be a value.

Comment: I don't think it is no use to compare Lisp's concepts with C++'s. Many concepts in programming languages are originated in Lisp.

Answer (score 0):

The value is `f1()`. However I don't get what you want to say about the relation between this and `operator+`.

Comment: This is C++, Lisp is a functional programming language with totally different concepts. As far as I remember (haven't done Lisp for years) in Lisp about everything is an expression, even program code. Some of Lisp's ideas just don't fit well with C++.

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator *evaluates* expressions - in this case it means that `true` is evaluated to `true` and then `f1()` is evaluated, which does nothing (the expression is evaluated to `void`).

I think this is one of the reasons why we have `void` in the language.

Please see this nice [article](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/1AUq5Di1/) for details.